# How to make proper multipart request using Karate when file is in --form?

Tags: karate

I need to implement such a request in Karate

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://test.env.com:8080/runner/runners' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
--header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001' \
--form 'createRunnerRequest={
  "name": "Test banner - 1",
  "header": "Test banner - 1 header",
  "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
  "priority": "1000",
  "button": {
    "objectType": "Button"
  },
  "isPersonalized": true,
  "startDate":"2020.01.01"
}' \
--form 'image=@/Users/me/Downloads/jpeg2000-home.jpg' \
--form 'ebrList='
```

So, my first attempt was to call just multipart for all my fields

```
  Scenario: 000
    Given url bannerServiceUrl + 'banners'
    And header content-type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001'
    And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token
    And multipart file image = { read: 'tst800x400.jpg', contentType: 'image/jpeg'}
    And multipart field createBannerRequest = read('personal-test-runner-1.json')
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

Response informed me, that I have no required request part - image.
So I have realized here, that I need to use form here... So I did.

```
  Scenario: 000
    Given url bannerServiceUrl + 'banners'
    And header content-type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001'
    And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token
    And form field image = read('tst800x400.jpg')
    And form field createBannerRequest = read('personal-test-runner-1.json')
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

And now I have an error, which says that application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 - is not supported Content Type.

Well, I know, when we use form, it bocomes default content type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

So, how could I write test right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `form field` won't work, this is multipart, so use `multipart file` or `field` for everything. Don't worry about the `boundary` Karate will do that part.

Can you try something like this:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* header Authorization = 'Bearer foo'
* multipart file image = { read: 'test.pdf', contentType: 'image/jpeg' }
* multipart file createBannerRequest = { read: 'test.json', contentType: 'application/json' }
* method post
* status 200
```

Comment: Hello, Peter!
Thanks! It worked, but I have used multipart field instead of file, like this
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* header Authorization = 'Bearer foo'
* multipart field image = read('test.pdf')
* multipart field createBannerRequest = read('test.json')
* method post
* status 200